# Adding Namespace for Extensions tag in AuthnRequest with Simplesamlphp

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I need to generate with Simplesamlphp library an AuthnRequest with the following Extensions tag

```
<samlp:Extensions xmlns:spid="https://spid.gov.it/saml-extensions">
   <spid:Purpose>PX</spid:Purpose>
</samlp:Extensions>
```

In Simplesamlphp's documentation is explained how to generate an [Extensions' child with namespace](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/saml:sp),
but it's not clear if it's possible to add a namespace to Extensions tag itself.

Any suggestion/clarification?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working for some weeks to update our version of simplesamlphp, we provide SPID, CIE, SPID eIDAS, ...

My company was using a version of the library from 2010 when I came here, after many many struggles I managed to update SPID completely and I'm almost done with CIE (and then there's the rest!).
Hope I can help you a bit for all I suffered.

To fix this issue I did this:

- added these rows inside *vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/XML/md/**EntityDescriptor.php*** to declare these namespaces globally (one for SPID and one for CIE)

  ```
    if($this->getIncludeSPIDns() === true){ //[EC] 14-03-'22
        $e->setAttribute ( 'xmlns:spid', 'https://spid.gov.it/saml-extensions' );
    }
    if($this->getIncludeCIEns() === true){ //[EC] 14-03-'22
        $e->setAttribute ( 'xmlns:cie', 'https://www.cartaidentita.interno.gov.it/saml-extensions' );
    }
  ```

I had to modify some files and declare these properties and their getters inside the EntityDescriptor class, because I wanted them to be dinamic:

*(config/**authsources.php**)*

```
'IncludeCIEns' => true, //Se impostato aggiunge il namespace (globalmente)
```

To add the Extensions block I did this:

1. I declared these properties inside the contacts property on *config/**authsources.php***

[image]

2. I marked these new properties as valid (so SAML would "pick them up") inside
   *lib/SimpleSAML/Utils/Config/**Metadata.php***

[image]

3. I read these values on
   *lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/**SAMLBuilder.php***
   *(this is the addContact function)*

[image]

4. I add the Extensions block and his children inside
   *vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/XML/md/**ContactPerson.php***

[image]

***Quick edit***: I'm working with **simplesamlphp 1.18.8** from 2020-09-02

P.S.: I wanted to provide code, I resorted to screenshots because of stackoverflow, what a waste of time just to post an answer. It was always saying my code wasn't indented properly (even if it was...), couldn't post my answer like it was, I resorted to enclosing it in pre tags (because the code sample wasn't working), it wasn't enough for this fancy site, had to convert them to screenshot...